# How does a GUI framework switch windows/window views/forms on Windows?

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi

From what I understand, a GUI will have its windows, window classes, and use these for the main windows and all the buttons and tabs etc.

These would all have handles and be rendered either with the Windows GDI or another backend such as OpenGL. When a user interacts, say by clicking on a widget, there will be a callback function/event handler and it'll do its job. But what is happening when the user clicks on a button that switches the (I'm not sure what to call this so I'll call it a "form" - by this I mean the visible set of all menus and widgets and things - like on Google Chrome I have this tab open right now and I could move to another one that displays a different website and GUI) form.

How does the GUI framework change all the windows on the screen? I can understand it could change what's being rendered with the API of choice, like OpenGL, but how does it get rid of all the old windows and load the new ones? Does it disable all the child windows through their handles, and just leave them there on the screen, but unseen and not accepting input? Does it delete everything and create new windows? How does it actually perform this change (efficiently too)? I may be making a mountain out of a molehill here - if I'm overthinking this please let me know!

I once made a very bad game, using c Win32, the GDI and Direct2D, and when you pressed "play" it'd go to the game, but I just had to hide the buttons in a very glitchy fashion - I had no clue how to perform the "switch."

I have never ever used a "proper" GUI framework like Qt nor have I ever built one myself so apologies for any errata in the question, please correct me. I ask because I want to make my own GUI framework as a long term project (nothing special just something I can say that I've achieved) and I am at a loss as to how I can implement this from a low-level perspective, or rather how industry standards such as Qt will implement this at the lowest possible level.

Any answers would preferably not refer to managed code or any scripting languages, or external libraries - I want to know how to do this in c Win32 + any arbitrary graphics API. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Desktop Window Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/dwm-overview). Also, [DirectComposition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directcomp/directcomposition-portal).

Comment: When the program is doing the drawing, it simply stops drawing the old things, and starts drawing the new things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accomplished by altering the z-order (the idea being that the windows form a stack from closest to the user to furthest away) of children at the appropriate level. The direct children of every window are in some z-order even if they are arranged such that they don't actually overlap.

For example, in the case of a tab control there will likely be a single child associated with each tab, that child representing the view for that tab. When a button is clicked the child for that tab is moved in the z-order so that is above all of its siblings (the forms for the other tabs). Those windows for the tab children will all be the same size (the empty area of the tab's client window) so bringing the child to the top of its parent's z-order will cover all other views.

In the case of the window's API you alter z-order placement via SetWindowPos, if you are going to roll your own (as WPF does) then you will need to re-implement this idea in some manner.

Comment: So right now as I use google chrome, it'll have all of the tabs actually running and displayed, but only the one that I'm using is on top of the z-stack?

Comment: and would that also mean that my user input only ever goes to the topmost window on the z-stack - something implemented by default by the Windows OS?

Comment: Keyboard messages go to the window with focus, mouse messages go to either the window that has captured the mouse (which will need to have been focused when it did so) or the window under the mouse, which will receive focus as part of that processing. I am not aware of any case where the focus window will not be on top of the z-order.